# How do I make member_id available for display?

Tags: php

I've been delving into this issue for hours but since I'm still a beginner to PHP, so I'm unable to figure out how should I edit this file. 
Can I have some hints on that please?

user.php

```
<?php
include('password.php');

class User extends Password{

    private $_db;

    function __construct($db){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_db = $db;
    }

    private function get_user_hash($username){  

        try {
            $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT password FROM members WHERE username = :username AND active="Yes" ');
            $stmt->execute(array('username' => $username));

            $row = $stmt->fetch();
            return $row['password'];

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
        }
    }

    public function login($username,$password,$member_id){

        $hashed = $this->get_user_hash($username);

        if($this->password_verify($password,$hashed) == 1){
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;                    
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username; //I added this line and it works well. 
            $_SESSION['member_id'] = $member_id; //I added this line but the member_id just won't display.
            return true;
        }   
    }

    public function logout(){
        session_destroy();
    }

    public function is_logged_in(){
        if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true){
            return true;
        }       
    }



}

?>
```

I used this way to display my username and it works perfect.

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
```

However, when I apply the same thing on member_id, it fails to display anything.

```
$member_id = $_SESSION['member_id'];
```

Thanks in advance and please bear with my stupidity for just a while. :(

Comment: Make sure `session_start();` is loaded and inside all pages using sessions.

Comment: Yes. I did. The login function works well and member-specific pages work correctly too. Is there anything I can do to tinker with user.php? The username can be echoed though since I have started my session.

Comment: Just to test, try using `SELECT * FROM members` instead of `SELECT password FROM members`; just a hunch.

Comment: `$member_id` is not initialised to any value when you use it.

Comment: would you please try to get output from `vardump($_SESSION);`.   with this code you can see anythings in session global array

Comment: Where are you setting `$member_id` to anything within that method? It's not magical. Did you mean to use a class property like `$this->member_id` (which would be set within one of your other methods)?

Comment: What `vascowhite` said makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I tried it and it still displays nothing.

Comment: @vascowhite How should I edit the file to make it available? I'm still very new to PHP so I just keep editing and trying.

Comment: You may also try adding it to your `function login($username,$password,$member_id)` then initializing it.

Comment: i see that you did not initialize $member_id in your code. i think this is your fault.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I edited the code above. It still doesn't work.

Comment: You may need to add that variable to your `get_user_hash()` function.

Comment: Look, *your code* has to *get* the value for `$member_id` *somewhere*. So this means probably from the `get_user_hash()` query, where you get `SELECT member_id, password ...`, then on "success", set a property on your class equal to `$this->member_id = $row['member_id'];` before you return.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code you have displayed, I suspect you already have the value of `$member_id` somewhere. I would suggest passing it into your login() method. Something like:-

```
public function login($username, $password, $member_id)
{
    //The rest of your function
}
```

Somewhere else in your code you will need to have something like:-

```
$user = new User();
$username = whereverYouGetUsernamesFrom();
$password = whereverYouGetPasswordsFrom();
$member_id = whereverYouGetMemberIdFrom();
$user->login($username, $password, $member_id);
```

Comment: I gave a [`comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105903/how-do-i-make-member-id-available-for-display#comment39069282_25105903) to that effect; OP says it didn't work.

Comment: I edited the code based on your suggestion. It still doesn't work.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I just saw that, he needs more help :)

Comment: @macytan88 You also need to change the code that calls the method, have you done that?

Comment: @macytan88 - You have to *get* the value you want in `$member_id` *somewhere*. See my comment under the question (further down the list).

Comment: @JaredFarrish I edited the code based on your suggestion (see the updated code above), but when I run the webpage, it shows error like this: "Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\xampp\htdocs\memberpage.php on line 17" and "Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\xampp\htdocs\memberpage.php on line 17"

Comment: @vascowhite I edited the code based on Jared's suggestion but to no avail.

Comment: Let's go back to the beginning: What is *`$member_id`*? What does it correspond to? A field in the `members` table? Is that field called something, say `id` or `member_id`? (The reason it isn't working is because you don't yet know how to interpret what we're saying into competent code.)

Comment: @macytan88 I think you need to put this code to one side, go and read a book/do a course and come back to it when you have more knowledge. This is not the place to be teaching the basics of PHP.

Comment: Yes, the name of the field is "member_id".

Comment: @vascowhite Sorry for troubling you.

Comment: I will try again and look through it in a more careful way. I will post more comments here if I got any. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @macytan88 I don't mean to be nasty, my suggestion is genuine. Trying to teach you this in comments will an be exercise in frustration for all of us, including you. You'll get much more from a book or a good course, honest.